# Archive Description split using <!-- more -->

Tags: wordpress

I've output my archive description as per below. However I would like to display the first part before the  tag in one place and the rest excluding the first part elsewhere in other tag. Is there a way to split this to output the two different data? It could be split just using the first paragraph instead.

```
the_archive_description( '<div class="taxonomy-description">', '</div>' );
```

Comment: Is this solved? You might consider marking an answer as accepted if it works to help others who come later.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [get_the_archive_description()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_archive_description/)
 instead. This returns the description instead of displaying it, which will allow you to manipulate it however you like using your own code before displaying (or not) parts of it. Kind of like this:

```
$myDescription = get_the_archive_description();
$sections = explode('<!-- more -->', $myDescription);
echo __( $sections[0], 'default' ); //Put this wherever you want to display the first part
echo __( $sections[1], 'default' ); //Put this wherever you want to display the rest
```